# How to generate RSA public key from private key?

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption, public-key, pyopenssl

I was reading a question on SO and find out that we can generate the public key from private key using `openssl` in python. Now I wonder how this works(the mathematics part) and  how can I implement the method in python or in C, without using the `openssl` or any other library ?

Comment: I thought the whole point of PKE was that it was practically impossible to derive the one key from the other, thus making secure asymmetric encryption possible. Both are (equal) parts of a modular arithmetic equation having huge exponents.

Comment: See [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25911/finding-public-exponent-e)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the private key is stored in CRT format (Chinese Remainder Theorem), there is no math involved; the format includes the public exponent. This is how OpenSSL tools "create" a public key from a private key.

If the private is not stored in CRT format, it's generally not feasible to compute the public exponent given the private exponent. You can, however, guess common public exponents and easily verify your guess.

Mathematically, in order to quickly compute one exponent using the other, you need to know the totient, a number computed from the factors of the modulus. And of course the security of RSA is predicated on the infeasibility of factoring the modulus. This relationship is symmetrical; it doesn't matter whether you know the public exponent and try to compute the private exponent, or vice-versa.